# Drawing boundary around nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a figure like the attached one which is produced by the below code. I want to draw a **dotted boundary** around some nodes as shown in the image. Whats the best way to do that? Any tips is highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={
at={(0.23,0.74)},
anchor=south}}
\begin{axis}[ xlabel = Field X Axis, ylabel = Field Y Axis  ,  xtick ={0, 50, 100}, ytick ={0, 50, 100}, legend entries ={Node, MC's Position, Base Station}]
\addplot[ gray, only marks] coordinates {(10,15) (10, 60) (2,55) (17, 16) (17,25) (1, 21) (5,45) (83, 10) (56,35) (25, 40)};
\addplot[orange, only marks, mark=square*, mark size=4] coordinates {(0,60) (60,80) (85,15)};
\addplot[cyan, only marks, mark=triangle*, mark size=7] coordinates {(0,5)};

\addplot[no markers, dashed, cyan] coordinates {(0,5) (0, 60)};
\addplot[no markers, dashed, cyan] coordinates {(0,5)(85,15)};
\addplot[no markers, dashed, cyan] coordinates {(0,5) (60,80)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{System Overview of  WRSN}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Would you provide a full MWE?

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger, done.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One possible way is named coordinates, around which you like to draw dotted line, and select shape of node which will fit selected coordinates. For this the TikZ library `fit` had to be add in document preamble:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=11cm,compat=1.13} % <--- added
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}% <--- added
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% for show figure only
\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={
at={(0.23,0.74)},
anchor=south}}
\begin{axis}[ xlabel = Field X Axis, ylabel = Field Y Axis  ,  xtick ={0, 50, 100}, ytick ={0, 50, 100}, legend entries ={Node, MC's Position, Base Station}]
\addplot[ gray, only marks] coordinates {(10,15) (10, 60) (2,55) (17, 16) (17,25) (1, 21) (5,45) (83, 10) (56,35) (25, 40)};
\addplot[orange, only marks, mark=square*, mark size=4] coordinates {(0,60) (60,80) (85,15)};
\addplot[cyan, only marks, mark=triangle*, mark size=7] coordinates {(0,5)};

\addplot[no markers, dashed, cyan] coordinates {(0,5) (0, 60)};
\addplot[no markers, dashed, cyan] coordinates {(0,5)(85,15)};
\addplot[no markers, dashed, cyan] coordinates {(0,5) (60,80)};

%%%% added
\coordinate (a) at (1, 21);
\coordinate (b) at (10,15);
\coordinate (c) at (17,16);
\coordinate (d) at (17,25);
    \node[ellipse, draw, thick, dotted, 
          fit=(a) (b) (c) (d)] {};
%%%%
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{System Overview of  WRSN}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:** The same result can be obtain without naming of coordinates:

```
%%%% added
\node[ellipse, draw, thick, dotted, 
      fit={(1, 21) (10,15) (17,16) (17,25)}] {};% <-- field of coordinates are inside {  }
%%%%
```

Comment: There's no need for named `coordinates` with `fit`, you can use `fit={(1,21) (10,15) (17,16) (17,25)}` with the coordinates whole list inside braces.